# jpa metamodel generation for external jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, jpamodelgen

I'm using hibernate-jpamodelgen (5.2.12) as maven dependency to create a metamodel for Criteria API. 
All entities are in an external jar-file (which dependency is in the pom.xml) and all entities are included in the persistence.xml. 
I can't generate the metamodel for the entities in the jar.
Is there any workaround to fix this?

Example:
Structure looks somethings like this.
project
-src
--entities
---LocalEntity.java
-dependencies
--SomeOtherEntities.jar

There is a jar-file which dependency is added to my pom.xml. The jar-file include some entity classes, like Class A and Class B.
For these classes i want to create the corresponding metamodel with the hibernate jpamodelgen. The classes A and B are also included in my persistence-unit. 
For my local entities the coresponding metamodel is created, but not for the entities of the included jar-file.

Comment: Try to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people here may help you.